# (Django)send data to View from javascript(ajax)

Tags: javascript, ajax, django

I want to send data(survey data) from the template to the server via ajax and store this data as CSV on the server. (I don't know jquery.) Currently, an error appears everywhere in URL, view, and Ajax. Help me with this. I can't understand how the request and response work if this is right...

javascript

```
function sendToServer(data){
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open("POST", "/polls/upload_csv/", true);
        req.send(data);
    }
```

urls.py

```
app_name = 'polls'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name = 'index'),
    path('survey/', views.survey, name = 'survey'),
    path('finish/', views.finish, name = 'finish'),
    path('upload_csv/', views.upload_csv, name = 'upload_csv'),
]
```

views.py

```
@csrf_exempt
def upload_csv(request):
    output_file = open('/media/result/resultList.csv', 'wb')
    writer = csv.writer(output_file)
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.is_ajax():
        writer.writerow(request.body)

    return 0
```

(I did not know what to write in return, so I left it blank.)

current error:

1. Internal Server Error: /polls/upload_csv/
2. output_file = open('/media/result/resultList.csv', 'wb')
   FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/media/result/resultList.csv'
3. "POST /polls/upload_csv/ HTTP/1.1" 500 75545
4. code 400, message Bad request syntax

Comment: try to remove the first `/` in the file path. And better to use the settings `MEDIA_ROOT` parameters.

Comment: check is the directory `media/result` exists.

Comment: @BearBrown thankyou for comment! i removed /  and that error gone. and error message has been changed. " if response.get('X-Frame-Options') is not None:
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'get' "

Comment: `return HttpResponse(status=201)`

Comment: @BearBrown one error message left!! "code 400, message Bad request syntax" and there is csv file but nothing inside. I think no data came

Comment: do you add the import for `HttpResponse`?

Comment: @BearBrown yes! Should data be json format? in my code data is String

Comment: possible, try `from django.http import JsonResponse` and `return JsonResponse({'result': 'created'})`